# How to track app installs from Google Play Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, google-analytics

Let's say I have an application. `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.my.app`

And I want to add to it `&referrer=5` That was `https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.my.app&referrer=5`

How can I track this `referrer` number after opening the application?

I found [this article](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/android/v4/campaigns), but it is for android. I also found [this](https://codelabs.developers.google.com/codelabs/flutter_ads#5) and [this](https://firebase.flutter.dev/docs/analytics/usage)

But it is not written how to get this parameter specifically for the link, and not generate it in the application. Please, help.

Comment: do you find any answer?

Comment: @AmitSingh Yes. I use appsflyer